# SQL Server 2008 - Decompressing a binary block

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an open query running from our BI environment to one of live clinical systems, the field I am interested in is stored on the target table as a binary block, I need a way in SQL Server 2008 to decompress this block. The field always holds 50 slots, the values stored in this field typically look like this:

```
 AELAABAIJICAFJAAAAAEEMAELKABAIJICAFJAAAAAIJIAEMEABAIJICAFJAAAAAIJIAEMOABAIJICAFJAAAAAIJIAENIABAIJICACAAAAAAAAAAEOCABAIJICACAAAAAAAAAAFBEABAIJICACAAAAAAAAAAFBOABAIJICACAAAAAAAAAAFCIABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFDCABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFDMABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFEGABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFHIABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFICABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFIMABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFJGABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFKAABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFKKABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFNMABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAFOGABAIJIFICAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: how could you decompress (i.e. from which index/char) ?

Comment: Without knowing the compression/encoding algorithm or how the data are stored, it's not really possible to give you an answer.  I suggest contacting your vendor for help.

Comment: Are you asking how to split this 1100 byte fixed-width binary column into separate 22 character values, returned as rows? A table-valued function would be the T-SQL tool for that job, or you could do it on the client side.

Comment: Yes back to the supplier on this one I think - thanks anyway all